# how to associate an AWS EC2 server to an internal domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm not seeing how to associate a EC2 Windows 2012 R2 server onto our internal domain.  Can anyone suggest how this works?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to consider the following:

1. Create a VPN of some sort from the server (or the VPC) back to your corporate network.
2. Ensure that the EC2 server can resolve your AD DNS records
3. Join the server to your domain as you would any other server.